# Move mail runtime error

Tags: vba, outlook

I have set up a macro in Outlook and it was working however in the last few days it has stopped filing received emails to specific folders and comes up with a ***Run Time Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method error***

First the code:

```
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objItem As Object
Dim FolderInbox As Folder
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem

'// Added - A collection to hold the IDs of message to be deleted
Dim cMAILS As Collection

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set FolderInbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set cMAILS = New Collection

For Each objItem In FolderInbox.Items

    ' here is the error         
    If objItem.ReceivedTime < Now - 50 And objItem.FlagStatus = 1 Then 

        ' Here is a series of code in place
        '  to move copies of messages to different folder

    Next

    On Error Resume Next

    Do While cMAILS.Count > 0

        Set MyItem = ns.GetItemFromID(cMAILS(1))

        If Not MyItem Is Nothing Then
            MyItem.Delete
        End If

        cMAILS.Remove (1)
    Loop
```

The line with the error is:

```
If objItem.ReceivedTime < Now - 50 And objItem.FlagStatus = 1 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Test that each object is a `mailitem`, because if not they might not have `ReceivedTime` or `Flagstatus`. Try something like:

```
If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
   If objItem.ReceivedTime < Now - 50 And objItem.FlagStatus = 1 Then
```

...